# Adding a disabled attribute to select box that can't be modified in Developer Options

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using jQuery prop() to add a disabled attribute into select box upon button click. However, if I removed the "disabled" property in Google Chrome developer options I'm able to access the select box again. I want to to know if there's a way  to remain the select box disabled even I modified it in the developer options.

Comment: Not possible. The user has complete control of the browser.

Comment: Absolutely not.

Comment: You can't. You should have some server validation to make sure what you receive is what you want.

Comment: Why are you asking - because of “security”? Then you should let go of the rather naive idea that any request reaching your server would have to be send by something like a “browser” to begin with.

Comment: I have a work around to make the select box to be just "text" instead of a select box though. I just want to know if that's possible even I modified the DOM. Now I know that is not possible, I will change my approach. Thank you all.

Comment: You can make any change to your DOM. But so can anyone else, using the browser console. Every single user has complete access to write whatever JS, CSS or HTML code they want. If you have an **endpoint** granting something (anything) based on frontend conditions... well, there's no way of preventing users from getting it. The only way is to make the check somewhere where they don't have access: in backend or by using a third party auth service (which - guess what? - it's still backend!)...

Comment: [Check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPl5i.png) out.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible if you want to make sure the sure the sure the user submits valid data then check it serverside not clientside. You do not have the power over the user when it's running client side.